# How tow create table with many columns(may be more than 300 columns) conveniently in dolphindb?

Tags: dolphindb

I want to create a table with a lot of columns in dolphidndb, but I can't find a convenient way?

If I use the `t = table(size:capacity,names,types)`, when I have many many columns, it is not convenient to modify and add or delete some columns.

```
colNames = ["col1","col2","col3","col4","col5","col6","col7","col8" ...]

colTypes = [STRING,DOUBLE,INT,LONG,SYMBOL,LONG,DATE,TIME,TIMESTAMP ...]

t = table(100:0,colNames,colTypes)
```

Is there more convenient way to do this work?

Answer (score 0):

The `table` function in DolphinDB has another way to organize columns.Instead of specifying a column name list and a column type list, one can specify columns one by one.

```
t= table(array(STRING, 0) as col1,
         array(DOUBLE, 0) as col2,
         ...
         )
```